# Photon speed for an observer at the photon sphere

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, photons, orbital-motion, time-dilation

I am asked to compute the orbital period of a photon, in the Scwarzschild spacetime, at the photon sphere for an observer at the same radius, $r^\star=3M$. I have computed the result, $\Delta T=6\pi M$ where $c=G=1$,comparing with the proper time of an observer at infinity. However, as the result gives directly $\Delta T=2\pi r^\star$, I wonder if I can skip making the calculation by inferring that, for the observer sitting at the photon sphere, the speed of the photon is exactly $c=1$. If that is the case, how can I argue that this is true?

Comment: locally the speed of light is always c, and since the photon's orbital radius doesn't change it stays that way in the frame of the observer, since his gravitational time dilation is the same at the same radius.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: In Schwarzschild coordinates this works since the angular components gθθ and gφφ are euclidean so that the circumference measured with stationary rulers is simply 2πr.

Comment: That was exactly my missing point! thank you so much!

Comment: @Yukterez According to the latest research of solving Maxwell equations in the photon sphere limit,- solution of wave equation isn't stable. Which means that photon soon either fall into black hole or escape from photon sphere. I don't remember exact paper where I've read about this instability. Though, I believe you can google it.

Comment: @Agnius Vasiliauskas wrote: *"According to the latest research of solving Maxwell equations in the photon sphere limit,- solution of wave equation isn't stable"* - LOL that's not according to the "latest" research, that is common knowledge since at least 100 years. In that case it doesn't matter anyway, since the question is only about 1 orbital period, so we assume no perturbations in this thought experiment.

Comment: I am also asked to show the orbit instability by considering the effective potential that comes out from the geodesics normalisation together with "energy" and "angular momentum" conservation. That was fairly easy. Although my teacher asked to show instability by perturbing the geodesic equation by retaining only first order terms and that doesn't work for me. I had to push it to second order terms. I'll share my undetailed computation just in case someone could confirm it's ok.

Comment: The radial equation that I was mentioning reads $\dot r ^2+f(r)/r^2 J^2=E^2$, where $f(r)=1-2M/r$. Evaluating at $r=r^\star+\nu$, where $\nu$ is a small perturbations gives me $\dot\nu^2=0$ at first order considering that $E^2/J^2=1/(27M^2)$ at $r^\star$. Therefore I have to take second order terms into account. Does that seem right?

Comment: @Yukterez Well, it depends on your view when modern science has started,- mine is that it started approx $250~\text{BC}$ with the arrival into this world of great Archimedes. In this case modern science time-span is about $2270$ years, so recent 100 years is just $4\%$ of this duration, so it still is latest in this respect. Of course, if you take modern science start as of industrial age,- boom of papers,- then 100 years is too far behind. But this too much exaggerates "now". Maybe after 1000 years or so science will be $1000\times$ more productive, so "now" could be an ancient like history.